# array from parameter comes to parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, publish-subscribe

I have a really strange situation in my actual javascript project. I created a custom event and put an array to this event

```
$.publish("merilon/TablesLoaded", getTables());
```

the object which subscribed this event didn't get with

```
$.subscribe("merilon/TablesLoaded", myfunc)
```

the two parameters event and the array in the function myfunc. Instead it get event and then each entry from the array as following parameter

so what i expectet is

```
myfunc(event, [obj1, obj2, obj3 ... objn]){...}
```

but i get

```
myfunc (event, obj1, obj2, obj3 ... objn){...}
```

I don't want a workaround. What i need is to understand why this happen and how i can prevent this. Anyone an idea?

Comment: $.publish/$.subscribe doesn't seem to be native jQuery. What plugin are you using ? Semms that there are plenty, which don't behave the same...

Comment: the problem is, that it's not possible to send arrays with the nettuts+ pub/sub model.

    $.publish("merilon/TablesLoaded", array);

is nothing else then

    $.trigger("merilion/TablesLoaded", event, array)

and when we watch under
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/
we can read 

    .trigger( eventType [, extraParameters] )
    eventTypeA string containing a JavaScript event type, such as click or submit.
    extraParametersAdditional parameters to pass along to the event handler.

Comment: so there is no way to prevent this, then the following:

 1. Write an other pub/sub system or use something diffrent
 2. use a workaround like

    $.publish("merilon/TablesLoaded", {o:getTables()});

if anyone see some other possibilities so you are welcome to share ur thoughts with me.

Comment: // Pub/Sub Implementation
(function($){
 var o = $({});
 $.each({
  on : "subscribe",
  trigger : "publish",
  off : "unsubscribe"
 }, function(key, api){
  $[api] = function(){
   o[key].apply(o, arguments);
  }
 });
})(jQuery);

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

```
(function($)
 {
 var o = $({}); 
 $.each(
       { on : "subscribe", trigger : "publish", 
         off : "unsubscribe" }, 
         function(key, api)
           { 
           $[api] = function()
                       {
                       o[key].apply(o, arguments); 
                       } 
            }
       ); 
       })(jQuery);
```